# How to "prove" recent analysis theorems without rigor?

Tags: mathematics

I asked this question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4833194/how-to-prove-analysis-famous-theorems-without-rigor) but I was told it would do better here

---

I always wonder how mathematicians proved theorems before Cauchy’s epsilon-delta proof. Since many "recent" theorems, such as the Stolz-Cesàro theorem, Cauchy limit theorem , Cauchy D'Alembert's Law, use epsilon-delta as part of their proofs, I wonder how Euler would have proved Stolz-Cesàro theorem for example. Although this theorem was not known to Euler, I am pretty sure that he could have "proved" it in minutes.

---

> **Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{*}{\infty}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone increasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty $,
> and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l$.

> **Stolz-Cesàro theorem case $\frac{0}{0}$:-**
> If $b_n $ is a monotone decreasing sequence and $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}  a_n = 0 $,
> and if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}- b_n}= l \in \overline{\mathbb{R}} $, then  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n }{b_n}=l$.

---

> **Cauchy D'Alembert's Law** If $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers and if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =l$  the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=l$

I want to see how to "prove" one of these theorems without rigor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "standard" way of proving such things without epsilontics would be to use infinitesimal analysis, at which Euler was an expert [of course](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/%7Ekatzmik/euler.html).  From this point of view, the formula $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\ell$ means that for all unlimited (informally, infinite) values of $n$, the ratio $\frac{a_{n+a}}{a_n}$ is infinitely close to $\ell$, and in fact it is enough to require such a relation of infinite proximity $\frac{a_{n+a}}{a_n}\approx\ell$ only for $n$ greater than some fixed unlimited $H>0$.

Since you are interested in arguments "without rigor", I will present a plausible argument that requires further work if one wants to make it fully OK.  Suppose $H=K^2$ where $K$ is of course still unlimited.  Then $K$ is "much" smaller than $H$.  Since the value on the limit is only dependent on the behavior of an infinite tail of the sequence, we can modify the original sequence by replacing the first $K$ terms in such a way that all the ratios $\frac{a_n}{a_n}$ are precisely $\ell$, without appreciably affecting either the limit of the ratios or the limit of the root.  What we obtain is that the sequence is appreciably of the form $C\ell^n$ (again, up to modifications of some initial terms).  Then the $n$-th root for $n>H$ will be appreciably $\sqrt[n]{C} \, \sqrt[n]{\ell^n}\approx \ell$.

Comment: A very good example! :)